# How can I unfollow all my contacts on LinkedIn at once?

Tags: linkedin

Is there any way to unfollow all my contacts on LinkedIn at once (without removing them)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Go the page that shows who you are following ([LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/feed/following/)) and run this code in the browser's developer console. It will go and click the unfollow button for you.

It also scrolls down the page so that more profiles load.

```
var buttons = $("button"),
 interval = setInterval(function(){
 var btn = $('.is-following');
 console.log("Clicking:", btn);
 btn.click();
 if (buttons.length === 0) {
    clearInterval(interval);
 }
 window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/feed/following/ will be the page with all the people you are following

Comment: Cache bug! https://imgur.com/gallery/NLFPWea

Comment: I noticed that sometimes you have to go on the "followers" tab since there's a cache bug (the followers tab also shows people you follow). Also, the scroll-to-load breaks randomly, so I added `window.scrollTo(0,0);` to improve reliability.